# Shiny DTedit, show or hide insert/new button based on rows_selected status in second DTedit table

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have two DTedit tables which are functionally related

I do not want users to get the Insert/New button in DT#2 when no row is selected in DT#1

I have `Table1_Results$rows_selected` to test if selection exists (length>0)

I also identified the id of the 'New button' in DT#2 as being `Table2_add`

But do not succeed to make the length of `Table1_Results$rows_selected` trigger the shinyjs show() or hide() action for DT#2

Could anyone please share some reactivity command to do this!

the following code is not working but illustrates my aim

```
observe(Table1_Results$rows_selected,{
    if (length(Table1_Results$rows_selected)) {
        shinyjs::show('Table2_add')
    } else {
        shinyjs::hide('Table2_add')
    }
})
```

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :    Operation not
> allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something
> that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

This manual test using a button works

```
observeEvent(input$showhide, {
    toggle('Table2_add')
})
```

So it is really the reactive testing of the `Table1_Results$rows_selected` which is lacking

Thanks in advance

---

In the code below:

- I cannot clear the selected row in the observed textoutput
- I do not succeed to hide the New button

```
Note: I use DTedit because it allows other features not shown here

AIMs: 
1) when no drink is selected, hide the New button for containers
2) manage <table>$rows_selected so that it reflects the current status
```

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyjs")
library("DT")
library("DTedit")

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    Drink_Results <- dtedit(
        input, output,
        name = 'Drink',
        thedata = data.frame(
            ID = c(1:3),
            drink = c('Tea', 'Coffea', 'Water'),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    )

    # create proxy to clear row selection (found 'Drinkdt' by looking in the source)
    Drink_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('Drinkdt')
    
    Container_Results <- dtedit(
        input, output,
        name = 'Container',
        thedata = data.frame(
            ID = c(1:3),
            Container = c('Cup', 'Glass', 'Pint'),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    )

    # create proxy to clear row selection    
    Container_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('Container')

    # manually toggle visibility for New button
    observeEvent(input$showhide, {
        shinyjs::toggle('Container_add')
    })
    
    # clear Drink row selection 
    observeEvent(input$clearrows, {
        Drink_proxy %>% selectRows(NULL)
    })

    # when no drink is selected, hide the New button for containers    
    observeEvent(Drink_Results$rows_selected, {
        if ( length(Drink_Results$rows_selected) ) {
            shinyjs::show('Container_add')
        } else {
            shinyjs::hide('Container_add')
        }
    })
    
    # attempt to react on clearing the row-selection
    choice <- reactive({
        paste0(Drink_Results$rows_selected, " - ", Container_Results$rows_selected)
    })
    
    # output current combination
    output$choice <- renderText({ as.character(choice()) })
    
}

ui <-  tagList(useShinyjs(),
               fluidPage(
                   shinyFeedback::useShinyFeedback(),
                   
                   h3('What will you drink?'),
                   uiOutput('Drink'),
                   
                   # manually clear row selections
                   actionButton(inputId="clearrows", label="clear selected drink", icon=icon('trash')),
                   
                   hr(),
                   
                   h3("What container do you prefer?"),
                   uiOutput('Container'),
                   
                   hr(),
                   
                   # manually hide the New button
                   actionButton(inputId="showhide", label="toggle New buttons", icon=icon('refresh')),
                   
                   hr(),
                   
                   # show current user choices
                   textOutput('choice'),
                   
               )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reactive for selected row is `input$Drinkdt_rows_selected` in your case, based on the source code.  If you use that, your code works fine.  Try this

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ##  could not install DTedit. So, made a copy of the function
  source("C:\\RStuff\\GWS\\dtedit.R", local=TRUE)

  Drink_Results <- dtedit(
    input, output,
    name = 'Drink',
    thedata = data.frame(
      ID = c(1:3),
      drink = c('Tea', 'Coffea', 'Water'),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
  name <- "Drink"

  # create proxy to clear row selection (found Drinkdt by looking in the source)
  Drink_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('Drinkdt')

  Container_Results <- dtedit(
    input, output,
    name = 'Container',
    thedata = data.frame(
      ID = c(1:3),
      Container = c('Cup', 'Glass', 'Pint'),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )

  # create proxy to clear row selection
  Container_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('Container')

  # clear Drink row selection
  observeEvent(input$clearrows, {
    Drink_proxy %>% selectRows(NULL)
    shinyjs::hide('Container_add')
  })
  
  sel <- reactive({!is.null(input[[paste0(name, 'dt_rows_selected')]])}) 
  observe({
    print(sel())
    print(input$Drinkdt_rows_selected)
  })

  # when no drink is selected, hide the New button for containers
  observe({
  #observeEvent(input[[paste0(name, 'dt_rows_selected')]], {
    if ( length(input[[paste0(name, 'dt_rows_selected')]])>0 ) {
      shinyjs::show('Container_add')
    }else {
      shinyjs::hide('Container_add')
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(Drink_Results$thedata, {
    message(Drink_Results$thedata)
  })

  observeEvent(input[[paste0(name, 'dt_rows_selected')]], ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
    # 'no' (NULL) row will be 'selected' after each edit of the data
    message(paste("Selected row:", input[[paste0(name, 'dt_rows_selected')]]))
  })


  # attempt to react on clearing the row-selection
  choice <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input[[paste0(name, 'dt_rows_selected')]])) {
      paste0("Drink not selected")
    }else {
      paste0(input[[paste0(name, 'dt_rows_selected')]], " - ", input$Containerdt_rows_selected)
    }
    
  })

  observeEvent(input$showhide, {
    toggle('Container_add')
  })
  
  # output current combination
  output$choice <- renderText({ choice() })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyFeedback::useShinyFeedback(),
  useShinyjs(),
  h3('What will you drink?'),
  uiOutput('Drink'),

  # manually clear row selections
  actionButton(inputId="clearrows", label="clear selected drink", icon=icon('trash')),

  hr(),

  h3("What container do you prefer?"),
  uiOutput('Container'),

  hr(),

  # manually hide the New button
  actionButton(inputId="showhide", label="toggle New buttons", icon=icon('refresh')),

  hr(),

  # show current user choices
  textOutput('choice'),

)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thanks, I had tried it already but not looked close enough.

Comment: When the shinny app starts there is no row selected in Table1 but also no change so the button is shown at startup in Table2 while it should be hidden.
When I now hide it in the Table2 code with 'show.insert = FALSE,' I cannot show it back even with the toggle button (maybe it's name is not defined so shinyjs cannot access it).

Comment: What does work better is (after removing show.insert=FALSE) to revert the logic and when I select a row in the related Table1 hide the button.
However when doing this, de-selecting the row does not show the button back (while the toggle button does the job).
It seems that the observeEvent does not get the right signal from that weird rows_selected object.
This is very puzzling!

Comment: Thanks so much @YBS, I spent more than a day failing on this and you made it work. Great help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

btw - it should be mentioned that the original code was not using the `jbryer` version of `DTedit` (v1.0.0) , which does not return `$rows_selected`. The modified `DavidPatShuiFong` version of `DTedit` (v 2.2.3+) does return `$rows_selected`.

The original code presented above used an `observeEvent` which, by default, has `ignoreNULL = TRUE`. That doesn't work, because if no row is selected, then `$rows_selected` will return `NULL`.

One option is to set `ignoreNULL = FALSE`. Unfortunately, this still leaves the problem that `shinyjs::hide` does not work on first execute, perhaps because 'Container_add' does not yet exist on first pass. Adding an `invalidateLater` which only executes a few times fixes that problem.

```r
library("shiny")
library("shinyjs")
library("DT")
library("DTedit")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    Drink_Results <- dtedit(
        input, output,
        name = 'Drink',
        thedata = data.frame(
            ID = c(1:3),
            drink = c('Tea', 'Coffea', 'Water'),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    )
    
    # create proxy to clear row selection (found 'Drinkdt' by looking in the source)
    Drink_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('Drinkdt')
    
    Container_Results <- dtedit(
        input, output,
        name = 'Container',
        thedata = data.frame(
            ID = c(1:3),
            Container = c('Cup', 'Glass', 'Pint'),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    )
    
    # create proxy to clear row selection    
    Container_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('Container')
    
    # manually toggle visibility for New button
    observeEvent(input$showhide, {
        shinyjs::toggle('Container_add')
    })
    
    # clear Drink row selection 
    observeEvent(input$clearrows, ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
        Drink_proxy %>% selectRows(NULL)
        shinyjs::hide('Container_add')
    })
    
    # when no drink is selected, hide the New button for containers
    invalidateCount <- reactiveVal(0)
    observe({
        # need to execute this observe more than once
        # (?because 'Container_add' does not actually exist first time?)
        if (isolate(invalidateCount()) < 1) {
            shiny::invalidateLater(200, session) # 200ms delay
        }
        isolate(invalidateCount(invalidateCount() + 1))

        print(paste0("row selected:", Drink_Results$rows_selected))
        if (!is.null(Drink_Results$rows_selected)) {
            shinyjs::show('Container_add')
        } else {
            shinyjs::hide('Container_add')
        }
    })
        
}

ui <-  tagList(useShinyjs(),
    fluidPage(

        h3('What will you drink?'),
        uiOutput('Drink'),
        
        # manually clear row selections
        actionButton(inputId="clearrows", label="clear selected drink", icon=icon('trash')),
        
        hr(),
        
        h3("What container do you prefer?"),
        uiOutput('Container'),
        
        hr(),
        
        # manually hide the New button
        actionButton(inputId="showhide", label="toggle New buttons", icon=icon('refresh')),
        
        hr(),
        
        # show current user choices
        textOutput('choice'),
        
    )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks David, I now have a fully functional shiny (with button hiding) thanks to YBS's additions. I did not notice what you say about the 'first time', for me it works out of the box. BTW, thanks a lot for this really improved version of DTedit.